# How to use the quadratic discriminant function (QDA) using Principal components (PCs)

Tags: r, pca, discriminant

I am studying by myself how to use the quadratic discriminant function using principal components. Indeed, there is some information about the linear discriminant function (LDA) with principal component. However, I couldn't find the QDA method with the principal component. I tried to apply the LDA method. However, I am unsure if I use the code correctly. Could you confirm my code? If there are any problems, please inform me about it.

Many Thanks

The code I used and the results are followed.

```
library(MASS)
library(adegenet)
library (tidyverse)

data(iris)
set.seed(1)
sample <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train <- iris[sample, ]
test <- iris[!sample, ]
train_spec<-train%>%select(-Species)
test_spec<-test%>%select(-Species)
train.s <- scale(train_spec)
test.s <- scale(test_spec)
train.pca <- prcomp(train.s, center = TRUE, scale. = FALSE)

d.dapc <- xvalDapc(x = train.s, grp = train$Species, scale = FALSE, center = TRUE, result = "groupMean", n.pca = 1:3, n.rep = 100)

n.pca <- as.numeric(d.dapc$`Number of PCs Achieving Lowest MSE`)
model <- qda(x = train.pca$x[,1:n.pca], grouping = train$Species)
test.pca.x <- as.matrix(test.s) %*% train.pca$rotation
pred<-predict(model ,nd=as.data.frame(test.pca.x),type="class")
```

[image: The result of the pred]